# Problems with build the pipeline in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

please help with jenkins.
I am bigenner in jenkins and  run jenkins using docker.
So when i type docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --restart always -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11  cpmmand in the cmd on my windows jenkins browser run.
Then i want to create project => frestyle project and in the Build select windows batch command.
Want to test the versions of the npm, newman, node. They all are installed on my machine.
when i save the project and click on build now.
Build fails.

[image]

Comment: Is this a windows machine?

Comment: Yes, someone sad to me that it is problem displayed cause jenkins running by Docker use Linux all the time. So i select Execute shell build step in the  project configuration. But console outpust display other problem:                                                         
 Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Rest_API
[Rest_API] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1898013192938806360.sh
+ node --version
/tmp/jenkins1898013192938806360.sh: 2: node: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: We would be able to answer the question  better if we can see the code. I think you should open another question since this seems unrelated to the previous question you had